# Adding Sublime Text back to gitbash command line

Tags: bash, path, sublimetext2

I'm new to programming and bash scripts, so this might be an easy question.

A while back, I installed Sublime Text 2 and did something with my system's Path, so that whenever I type

$ sublime_text file.py

it would either open or create file.py in the current folder with Sublime.

However, if I do that now, I get an error message that "This build of Sublime has expired."

Any ideas on what I need to do now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using a beta build of Sublime Text 2. Update your application and make sure you have the latest version by downloading the latest build from [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't work at first, but it turns out I used the wrong version (x64 instead of the normal install), and re-installing that version works great.